# Pandas Cleaning up

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have an excel file in this format and I am trying to read it in Pandas and clean it up:

[image: I have an excel file in this format and I am trying to read it in Pandas and clean it up]

I read in the file with read_excel and created a multiindex level starting from row 7([2013,2016,2017...]

```
    df= pd.read_excel(PATH_CY_TABLE, header= [7,8,9])
```

This is how it read in:

[image: This is how it read in:]

Ideally, I want to clean up to look something like this:

[image: Ideally, I want to clean up to look something like this:]

What steps can I follow to get it this format?
Couple of things I have tried are:
1. remove the level 1 of multi index: where the columns names appears as 'unnamed...'

```
    df.columns= df.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

This gives me an error: *IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2*

2. Stacking the columns indices:

   ```
   df.stack()
   ```

This gives me an error: *TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'*

3. I tried this:

   ```
   df.columns=df.columns.get_level_values(0)
   ```

And this gave me the first level of MultiIndex as [2013, 2013, 2013, 2016,2016,2016...]. But I want the output df to have two levels of indices here: Level 0 and Level 3.

As a first step I am looking to remove the 'Unnamed...' columns names. I have tried to post the df as an output instead of pictures, but unsure how to do them in the correct way- when I copy paste from jupyter notebook, they paste all messed up. I am quite new to posting questions here..so still working my way around.

Comment: Having reproducible data examples and some code for what you have tried will help you get assistance.

Comment: please post a small sample df and an expected df against it as text(no images) , with a brief explaination of the logic. Thanks

Comment: `dropna(how='all')` does that work?

Comment: I have tried to post the df as an output instead of pictures, but unsure how to do them in the correct way- when I copy paste from jupyter notebook, they paste all messed up. I am quite new to posting questions here..so still working my way around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't still able find a better way to post my output but I worked around a way to clean up the file to the desired output:

I sliced the MultiLevelIndex level 0 to match year I want(2017)

```
    df1= df
    df1= df1.iloc[:, df1.columns.get_level_values(0)== 2017]
```

Out:

```
                                                     Number      MOE1 (±)  Rate  
    Total..........................................…  323156.0    123.0     X   
    NaN                                                    NaN      NaN   NaN   
    Any health plan……………….……...…                      294613.0    662.0  91.2   
    NaN                                                    NaN      NaN   NaN   
   .Any private plan2,3………………………                     217007.0   1158.0  67.2
```